# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I wrote a code for tictactoe game, however it it showing me this error at run time:

```
Exception: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tictactoe.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe/com.tictactoe.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
```

My `MainActivity` is:

```
package com.tictactoe.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //protected DrawerLayout mdrawerLayout;

    /*Game plan*/
    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    // Buttons making up the board
    private Button mBoardButtons[];
    private Button mNewGame;

    // Various text displayed
    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mPlayerOneCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mPlayerTwoCount;
    private TextView mPlayerOneText;
    private TextView mPlayerTwoText;

    private int mPlayerOneCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mPlayerTwoCounter = 0;

    private boolean mPlayerOneFirst = true;
    private boolean mIsSinglePlayer = false;
    private boolean mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;

    boolean mGameType = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("gameType");

    private Button[] getmBoardButtons() {
        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
        addListenerOnButton();

        // setup the textviews
        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mPlayerOneCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humanCount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mPlayerTwoCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);
        mPlayerOneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.human);
        mPlayerTwoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.android);

        // set the initial counter display values
        mPlayerOneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerOneCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mPlayerTwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerTwoCounter));

        // create a new game object
        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        // start a new game
        startNewGame(mGameType);

        return mBoardButtons;
    }

    //mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.play) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Play option selected!");
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Exit option selected!");
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton(){

        mNewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewGame);

        mNewGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startNewGame(mIsSinglePlayer);
            }
        });
    }

    // start a new game
    // clears the board and resets all buttons / text
    // sets game over to be false
    private void startNewGame(boolean isSingle)
    {

        this.mIsSinglePlayer = isSingle;

        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
            ///mBoardButtons[i].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank));
        }


        if (mIsSinglePlayer)
        {
            mPlayerOneText.setText("User:");
            mPlayerTwoText.setText("Android:");

            if (mPlayerOneFirst)
            {
                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
                mPlayerOneFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, move);
                mPlayerOneFirst = true;
            }
        }

        mGameOver = false;
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if (mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    if (mIsSinglePlayer)
                    {
                        setMove(mGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);

                        int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                        if (winner == 0)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                            int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                            setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, move);
                            winner = mGame.checkForWinner();
                        }

                        if (winner == 0)
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                        else if (winner == 1)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                            mTieCounter++;
                            mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }
                        else if (winner == 2)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                            mPlayerOneCounter++;
                            mPlayerOneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerOneCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                            mPlayerTwoCounter++;
                            mPlayerTwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerTwoCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                            setMove(mGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);
                        else
                            setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, location);

                        int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                        if (winner == 0)
                        {
                            if (mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                            {
                                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_two);
                                mIsPlayerOneTurn = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_one);
                                mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (winner == 1)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                            mTieCounter++;
                            mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }
                        else if (winner == 2)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_player_one_wins);
                            mPlayerOneCounter++;
                            mPlayerOneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerOneCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                            mIsPlayerOneTurn = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_player_two_wins);
                            mPlayerTwoCounter++;
                            mPlayerTwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerTwoCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                            mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // set move for the current player
    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player, location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        if (player == mGame.PLAYER_ONE)
            mBoardButtons[location].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_x));
        else
            mBoardButtons[location].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_o));
    }

}
```

and TicTacToeGame.class is:

```
package com.tictactoe.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe;

/**
 * Created by Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL on 02/16/2017.
 */

import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToeGame {

    private char mBoard[];
    private final static int BOARD_SIZE = 9;

    public static final char PLAYER_ONE = 'X';
    public static final char PLAYER_TWO = '0';
    public static final char EMPTY_SPACE = ' ';

    private Random mRand;


    public static int getBOARD_SIZE() {
        // Return the size of the board
        return BOARD_SIZE;
    }

    public TicTacToeGame(){

        mBoard = new char[BOARD_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
            mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;

        mRand = new Random();
    }

    // Clear the board of all X's and O's
    public void clearBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        {
            mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;
        }
    }

    // set the given player at the given location on the game board.
    // the location must be available, or the board will not be changed.
    public void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mBoard[location] = player;
    }

    // Return the best move for the computer to make. You must call setMove()
    // to actually make the computer move to that location.
    public int getComputerMove()
    {
        int move;

        // First see if there's a move O can make to win
        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
            {
                char curr = mBoard[i];
                mBoard[i] = PLAYER_TWO;
                if (checkForWinner() == 3)
                {
                    setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
                    return i;
                }
                else
                    mBoard[i] = curr;
            }
        }

        // See if there's a move O can make to block X from winning
        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
            {
                char curr = mBoard[i];
                mBoard[i] = PLAYER_ONE;
                if (checkForWinner() == 2)
                {
                    setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
                    return i;
                }
                else
                    mBoard[i] = curr;
            }
        }

        // Generate random move
        do
        {
            move = mRand.nextInt(getBOARD_SIZE());
        } while (mBoard[move] == PLAYER_ONE || mBoard[move] == PLAYER_TWO);

        setMove(PLAYER_TWO, move);
        return move;
    }

    // Check for a winner and return a status value indicating who has won.
    // Return 0 if no winner or tie yet, 1 if it's a tie, 2 if X won, or 3
    // if O won.
    public int checkForWinner()
    {
        // Check horizontal wins
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i += 3)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[i+1] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[i+2] == PLAYER_ONE)
                return 2;
            if (mBoard[i] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[i+1] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[i+2] == PLAYER_TWO)
                return 3;
        }

        // Check vertical wins
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if (mBoard[i] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[i+3] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[i+6] == PLAYER_ONE)
                return 2;
            if (mBoard[i] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[i+3] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[i+6] == PLAYER_TWO)
                return 3;
        }

        // Check for diagonal wins
        if ((mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                mBoard[4] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                mBoard[8] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
                mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                        mBoard[4] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                        mBoard[6] == PLAYER_ONE)
            return 2;
        if ((mBoard[0] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                mBoard[4] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                mBoard[8] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
                mBoard[2] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                        mBoard[4] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                        mBoard[6] == PLAYER_TWO)
            return 3;

        // Check for a tie
        for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
        {
            // if we find a number, then no one has won yet
            if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
                return 0;
        }

        // If we make it through the previous loop, all places are taken, so it's a tie
        return 1;
    }
}
```

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get extras from a field in the Activity, i.e. you are trying to get the extras before the Activity is created. If you get the extras from the **onCreate** method, it won't be a null value.

Example:

```
boolean mGameType;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGameType = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("gameType");
    ...
}
```

EDIT: If you want to send extra from one Activity to another, you should start it this way:

```
startActivity(new Intent(SenderActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
            .putExtra("gameType", true));
```

Comment: I added that line, it didn't work. I got same error... Can you please help me?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni how do you send the extra **gameType** from the sender Activity?

Comment: Ummm... I don't have any idea

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I updated my answer. See the code after the edit.

Comment: But there is only one activity in my code. `TicTacToeGame` class is for TicTacToe operations

Comment: @AjayKulkarni then it seems that you are not using **mGameType** at all. You should remove it and try different implementation. Maybe setting a boolean (mGameType) by prompting the user what the game type will be (played by one player or by two players).

Comment: I removed `gameType` and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @AjayKulkarni You are welcome. Please mark my answer as "accepted".